# PHP class arrays

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop, namespaces

I have created a class to get user parameters like below, but im having trouble showing data.
Here is what I have done:

```
namespace App\Users;

class Person
{

    public $_user;
    public $_userDataParams;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->_user = $user;
        $this->_userDataParams = self::$this->getData();
    }

    public function function_1()
    {
        $obj[$this->_user]['user_fullname'] = 'John Doe';
        $obj[$this->_user]['user_role'] = 'Button-Pusher';
        $this->_userDataParams = $obj;
        return $this->_userDataParams;
    }

    public function function_2()
    {
        $obj[$this->_user]['experience'] = '4 Months';
        $obj[$this->_user]['experience_date'] = '2017-01-01';
        $this->_userDataParams = $obj;
        return $this->_userDataParams;
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        $this->_userDataParams = array_merge(self::$this->function_1(),self::$this->function_2());
        return $this->_userDataParams;
    }

}

echo "<pre>";
$person = new Person("john");

print_r($person);
```

This is what it prints :

```
App\Users\Person Object
(
    [_user] => john
    [_userDataParams] => Array
        (
            [john] => Array
                (
                    [experience] => 4 Months
                    [experience_date] => 2017-01-01
                )

        )

)
```

I need to add to `_userDataParams` also `function_1` array of data.
Can someone help please.
Thank you.

Comment: i think the problem is array_merge try array_merge_recursive

Comment: @mr.void that was pretty nice :)